# One background image for multiple screens in flutter

Tags: flutter

On every page I do like this:

```
return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.black,
          image: DecorationImage(
            image: AssetImage('assets/images/background.png'),
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
            colorFilter: new ColorFilter.mode(Colors.black.withOpacity(0.9), BlendMode.dstATop),
          )
        ),
        child:...
 );
```

Are there anyway I only use one image for all screens in flutter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define your custom widget for this..

```
customContainer(child){
    return Container(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.black,
          image: DecorationImage(
            image: AssetImage('assets/images/background.png'),
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
            colorFilter: new ColorFilter.mode(Colors.black.withOpacity(0.9), BlendMode.dstATop),
          )
        ),
        child: child,
);
}
```

And.. wherever you need it..

```
return Scaffold(
    body: customContainer(yourChildWidget),
);
```

Hope it answers your question..

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, there is no one function/widget/method/whatever with which you can set something globally. What you can probably do is to put the common code in a reusable class  say MyBackground() and use it like this everywhere :

```
return Scaffold(
      body: MyBackground(),
        child:...
 );
```

This way, you can re-use this code wherever needed and a change in one place will affect everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to extract the code for the `Scaffold` with this background into a custom reusable widget that takes in a child widget from the individual screens like below:

```
class ScaffoldWithBackground extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget child;

  ScaffoldWithBackground({@required this.child});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Container(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.black,
                image: DecorationImage(
                  image: AssetImage('assets/images/background.png'),
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  colorFilter: new ColorFilter.mode(
                      Colors.black.withOpacity(0.9), BlendMode.dstATop),
                )),
            child: child));
  }
}
```

And in your individual screens you use it like this:

```
return ScaffoldWithBackground(
    child:...//Code for screen
);
```